# Trouble with functional creation and rendering of div in sub of a sub

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, components

I'm sure im missing some key element of understanding because this file gets exported and used in another file and then that is exported to another file and then that last file in the chain is what is sent to react.DOM. but why can't I make my components in a function in this file and have them be rendered. I'm not understanding something about the chain and how many exported files you can have and how i guess nested they can be.... help please. Cause if I do this at the surface level of the file chain it works fine but not this far down...

import React, { Component } from 'react';

```
import './Css_files/OfficeComponent.css';

class OfficeComponent extends Component {

  pic_span_nurse(props){
      return(
          <div className="row box_infoz">
            <div className="col-xs-3">
              <h1>picture</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-9">
              <h5>So this has noew changed to the office part where we have staff in this box and directions on the bottom</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <pic_span_nurse/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default OfficeComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very surprised doing `<pic_span_nurse/>` works at all, in any context.
I think you're mistaking the concept of what a Component is. A method inside a Component is not considered a component. It is still a method. Which means you have to render `pic_span_nurse` like you would when you return a method. This should definitely work:

```
{this.pic_span_nurse()}
```

The curly braces mean it's JavaScript code that should be interpreted, rather than literal text.

Also, JavaScript style guides encourage (read: must) naming to be done in camelcase, not underscores.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a separate component and use it in your code.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './Css_files/OfficeComponent.css';
const Pic_span_nurse =(props)=>{
      return(
          <div className="row box_infoz">
            <div className="col-xs-3">
              <h1>picture</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-9">
              <h5>So this has noew changed to the office part where we have staff in this box and directions on the bottom</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    }

class OfficeComponent extends Component {      
  render() {
    let compProps = {};//the props of the Pic_span_nurse component
    return (
        <div>
          <Pic_span_nurse {...compProps}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default OfficeComponent;
```

Or you can use a function call to render the necessary html.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './Css_files/OfficeComponent.css';

class OfficeComponent extends Component {

  pic_span_nurse=(props)=>{
      return(
          <div className="row box_infoz">
            <div className="col-xs-3">
              <h1>picture</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-9">
              <h5>So this has noew changed to the office part where we have staff in this box and directions on the bottom</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          {this.pic_span_nurse(this.props)}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default OfficeComponent;
```